#  Insert text at front of file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I insert text at the beginning of a file that already exists using a command in a BAT file?

Mock me if you like but my googling skills failed me :)

Comment: Can you give an example of what text you'd like inserted? Is it just a short string, the Gettysburg Address, or *Gone With The Wind*?

Comment: @JonathanM: Why does that matter?

Comment: @Rocket, good question. I was asking because the techniques are different if you're taking a command-line parm and appending to a file, versus the content of another file and appending to a file. The way you get the text to append is different.

Comment: Thanks guys.  The use case was that I had a directory full of database  table creation scripts (many, many) and I wanted to quickly add "If exists... drop " to the front of them.  The table name is the same as the file name, so its possible.  So, we're talking about appending maybe 100 characters or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot insert at the beginning of a file using the batch file lang on windows.
But, you can put your new stuff in a file and use

```
copy /b <beginningfile> + <endfile> <newfile>
```

to create the file you're after.

Answer (score 4):

The [JimR solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160116/1012053) works if the inserted text already exists in a file.

You can functionally make it the same as editing the original file by moving the new file to the old name.

If the text to be inserted does not yet exist in a file, then you can do the following:

```
>originalFile.txt.new (
  echo New line of text
  echo A blank line follows this one
  echo(
  echo Another line of text
  type originalFile.txt
)
move /y originalFile.txt.new originalFile.txt
```

If you need text inserted at the front of the existing line 1, then:

```
>originalFile.txt.new (
  <nul set /p "=Prefix to insert in line 1: "
  type originalFile.txt
)
move /y originalFile.txt.new originalFile.txt
```